# Visual Studio Build, Clean and rebuild

Tags: visual-studio

For some reason when I'm now trying to rebuild my Visual Studio solutions,

it does not use the latest code that I just updated.

The only way I can get the debugger to use the latest code, is to clean the solution then do a complete rebuild.

I'm not sure what I changed to get this to happen?

Comment: Are you developing a web app or desktop app? Do you have more than one projects in the solution?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to remove any reference to the dll. 
Then you just clean the solution. 
After that, go and check in the bin folder of your solution.
If exists, please delete that dll.

After that once more clean the solution. 
Then Add reference to the project( not to the dll).
Then you just build/rebuild the solution and check.

Most probably you may get your problem solved.

***Note :*** Please open your solution in Administrator mode. Sometimes the local users may not have enough permissions. (Not mandatory)

Comment: This may solve the issue. Also try in Administrator mode if not able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you have referenced to a library project you may have referenced to the dll only not to the project. Try referencing to the project.

Comment: I have referenced to the project ...not to the DLLs